# Regular definitions of numbers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, regular-language

I'm currently working in the following excercise:

> Build the regular definition of complex numbers taking into account the cartesian and polar form.

$$digit \rightarrow 0|1| \dots |9$$
$$digits \rightarrow digit \; digit^{*}$$
$$polar \rightarrow (\epsilon(+|-)digits)\theta$$
$$complex \rightarrow \epsilon  \; digits \; i  $$

I'm not sure about my approximation to the polar way and also the definition of the complex numbers, I'm still quite beginner in the area.

I would really appreciate any hint or help and thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: No floating point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try
$$ 
\begin{align}
nonzerodigit\to& \textbf1|\textbf2|\textbf3|\textbf4|\textbf5|\textbf6|\textbf7|\textbf8|\textbf9\\
digit\to& \textbf0|nonzerodigit\\
decimals\to&  digit\ digit^*\\
positivdecimals\to &digit^* nozerodigit\ digit^*\\
positiveinteger\to& nonzerodigit\, digit^*\\
positivereal\to& positiveinteger | \textbf{0.}positivedecimals | positiveinteger\textbf . decimals\\
nonzeroreal\to& (\textbf-|)positivereal\\
complex\to& \textbf0|nonzeroreal|nonzeroreal\ \textbf{i}\\&|nonzeroreal (\textbf+|\mathbf-)positivereal\ \textbf i \\
&|positivereal\  \textbf{exp(}positivereal\ \textbf{ i)}
\end{align}$$